# Angular2+, SpringBoot 2.1.9, Keycloak: CORS configuration doesn't work

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, keycloak

I'm setting up the application which includes Angular 8 frontend + Spring Boot API. Additionally I have Keycloak SSO.
My solution is based on [this example code](https://github.com/cternes/slackspace-angular2-spring-keycloak) which I wanted to base on newer versions of dependencies.

### The Problem

CORS policy doesn't want to let me do a request to backend API to gain resource.
The login seems to work fine.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCkBY.png

I have already tried making a CorsFilter, @CrossOrigin on method and/or controller, and overriding WebMvcConfigurer addCorsMapping method.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>eu.example</groupId>
<artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>e-diary</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Log on DEBUG level**

https://gist.github.com/K4masz/7ab960bc864625799727ca4c0d4ce61d

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Cors? The logs say ”Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point”

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thats interesting. based on chrome dev tools error I was assuming it was the problem of cors. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: run the spring application with debug logging activated for spring security and you will see what you got denied for in detail. `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` in your `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Add WebConfig file in to Spring Boot

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```